# Wicket 1.5 Autocomplete Textfield onUpdate Behavior not called

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, wicket, textfield

My AutoCompleteTextField (getChoices method implemented and working):

```
AutoCompleteTextField<String> objectDescription = new AutoCompleteTextField<String>("objectDescription") { 
     getChoices() {...}
}
```

To this textfield I add:

```
objectDescription.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior()) {
     onUpdate() {....}
}
```

The `onUpdate` method gets called everytime I write something in my textfield but not when I choose some item from the autocomplete menu. The string from the menu is written to the textfield but only calls the onUpdate when another change is made.

Edit: Before Wicket 1.5 this was working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange")`.

The `OnChangeAjaxbehavior()` seems to fire at every change (uses the Javascript `Wicket.ChangeHandler`), like in every key press.

Using an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` will add the event listener to `onChange` javascript events, like in focusing out of the textfield with a different value, or in selecting a value from the autocomplete list.

Still not sure why doesn't `OnChangeAjaxbehavior extends AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` inherit this logic from `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`, there must be something it's overriding.

**UPDATE** This might well be the reason why `onchange` javascript events are being ignored when using `OnChangeAjaxBehavior`. The source code for `Wicket.ChangeHandler`, found in wicket-ajax.js, sets handlers for different events:

- Backs up the `onchange` event handler in `onchangeoriginal`:

```
obj.onchangeoriginal = obj.onchange
```

- If the browser is IE, Safari, and some other, it assigns the original `onchange` event handler to `onKeyUp`, `onpaste` and `oncut`.
- If not, it assigns the original `onchange` event handler to `onInput`.
- Finally, it always removes the `onchange` event handler:

  ```
  obj.onchange = function(event){
      Wicket.stopEvent(event);
  }
  ```

The code in `wicket-autocomplete.js` seems to be manually firing the `onchange` event handler at item selection. Probably it should be checking for `obj.onchangeoriginal` first.

So, being this js executed in `OnDomReady`, I doubt it's possible to make those two behaviors coexist. Maybe it's time to file a new JIRA?

This might be a slightly related issue: [WICKET-2424: OnChangeAjaxBehavior + DatePicker do not work together](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-2424)

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! Don't know the logic behind this behavior, seems like a bug for me...

Comment: I found this issue too... should've been fixed with this change: `obj.onchangeoriginal = obj.onchange;` but still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Yeah... It seems that they should be checking for `obj.onchangeoriginal` first in `wicket-autocomplete.js`.

Comment: I've submitted an issue regarding this matter: [WICKET-4204](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4204).

Comment: I don't know if this is related to this issue, but the `AjaxIndicator`-Image isn't invoked either...